# Google Calendar API prompting authorization every two hours

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

My goal :
Having a cron task that reaches Google Calendar each hour to get new events.

I have been using the regular Google Calendar API example here :
https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php

- I log into my account
- I copy/paste the verification code
- Everything works well, the first token is OK
- When the first token expires, it is replaced by one without a refresh token and an expire_in not null (3600)

So after the second token expires, Google asks for the verification code again.

What should I do to have only one verification step and then refresh the token so I can access my calendar for as long as I want?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a service account.  Service accounts are like dummy users that can be pre approved access.

Once you have created the service account you can take the service accounts email address grant it access to the calendar you are trying to access.  It will then have access to that calendar when ever you need.  You wont need to worry about its access expiring.

If for some reason you dont want to use a service account. you could consent  your application once and then save the refresh token.  You can then use the refresh token to request a new access token when ever the access token has expired.